# Are minOccurs and maxOccurs defaults ever not 1 in an XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

Is the default value for `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` attributes ever not `1` for an xml schema?

I am wondering if it is safe to simply remove all `minOccurs="1"` and `maxOccurs="1"` because they are *(possibly, depending on the answer)* just clogging the schema up with superfluous text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The default value for both the minOccurs and the maxOccurs attributes is 1. See this section of the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#ref6)

Answer (score 3):

minOccurs and maxOccurs have a default value of 1, and thus it is safe to remove them.

You may want to watch out if your schema contains extensions of a complexType though. As they might change the values, which are inherited.

Comment: Wouldn't extending `complexType` be bad practice?

Comment: I've never done so myself, but I believe it's just a form a re-useability similar to inheritance in an Object Oriented programming language.